# How to manipulate general output (not numbers or variables) in C?

Tags: c, setw

Ok so I am doing this assignment in C and I was wondering if C has output manipulators like setw from c++? I know how to manipulate numbers and stuff but I don't know how to manipulate general output. E.g

I want to output "process" and "count" with a width of 5:

printf("Process") and then printf("count") with a width of 5 in between them. How can I do this?

Comment: Add a `\t`(tab) in the printf

Comment: There's also a `printf( const char * format, ... )`, so `printf( "%s     %s\n", "Process", "count");` (there are 5 spaces between the first `%s` and the last `%s`) check out [C Tutorial – printf, Format Specifiers, Format Conversions and Formatted Output](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure setw(n) works like you think it does. If you compile and run this C++ code . . .

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Process"
              << std::setw(5) << "count" << '\n';
}
```

then you'll get this output.

```
Processcount
```

Use `setw(10)` instead, and you'll get *this* output.

```
Process     count
```

In C, printf() lets you specify the column width.

```
/* File: code/c/test.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%s", "Process");
  printf("%10s\n", "count");

  return 0;
}
```

That will print "Process" first, then print "count" in a field that's 10 characters wide. The string "count" itself is five characters. That leaves five blanks between the two strings.

```
$ gcc -Wall code/c/test.c
$ ./a.out
```

```
Process     count
```

Embedding a tab like this `printf("Process\tcount\n");` won't give you five blanks between the two words.

```
Process count
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a \t between "process" and "count" will put a tab between the two string.

```
printf("Process\tcount\n");
```